# Pandas exercise: Group by two values and find the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on this pandas exercise: https://github.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/blob/master/03_Grouping/Occupation/Exercises_with_solutions.ipynb

The dataframe I am working with has an age, gender and occupation column. The question asks for each combination of occupation and gender, calculate the mean age.

I was wondering what is the difference between my solution:

```py
users.groupby(['occupation', 'gender']).age.mean()
```

And the solution suggested in the answer:

```py
# create a data frame and apply count to gender
gender_ocup = users.groupby(['occupation', 'gender']).agg({'gender': 'count'})

# create a DataFrame and apply count for each occupation
occup_count = users.groupby(['occupation']).agg('count')

# divide the gender_ocup per the occup_count and multiply per 100
occup_gender = gender_ocup.div(occup_count, level = "occupation") * 100

# present all rows from the 'gender column'
occup_gender.loc[: , 'gender']
```

The values I have gotten in my solution is certaintly different from the answer, but I don't understand what is different under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was correct. Silly me. I was looking at the answer for the following question.